# How to get hours from array of datetime attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

```
=> [#<WelcomeCall id: 16, call_at: "2013-11-06 12:00:00">,
    #<WelcomeCall id: 17, call_at: "2013-11-06 13:00:00">,
    #<WelcomeCall id: 18, call_at: "2013-11-06 17:00:00">,
    #<WelcomeCall id: 19, call_at: "2013-11-06 14:00:00">]
```

I would like to get an array of hours form all these **WelcomeCall** objects.

```
=> [12, 13, 17, 14]
```

WelcomeCall is rails model.

I used for that:

```
  def self.scheduled_hours date
    by_date(date).map do |wc|
      wc.call_at.hour
    end
  end
```

but maybe there is better way?

Comment: We cannot give you an answer unless you tell us what that `WelcomeCall` class is, especially, how to access the attribute in question, and what class that attribute belongs to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `map`.

Try something like this:

```
new_array = old_array.map{ |welcome_call| welcome_call.call_at.strftime('%H').to_i }
```

Assuming that your welcome_call.call_at is a Date. If it's not a Date object, then try:

```
new_array = old_array.map do |welcome_call|
    date = Date.parse(welcome_call.call_at)
    date.strftime('%H').to_i
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the array and parse the call_at datetime object using `strftime('%H').to_i`.

Answer (score 0):

```
welcome_calls.map {|w| w.hour}
```

Parsing the Date to a String and then reparsing the String to a Fixnum is not as fast I think.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried something and it worked, i'm not sure if it's the right way.

```
var = Model.all
t = var.collect(&:call_at)
hours_arr = []
t.each do |value|
hours_arr << value.time.hour
end
```